# i m getting error Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am getting error while using Firefox version 51 with selenium 2.48 
getting blank page of Firefox.

error :

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
>   Firefox console output:   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try to use below portion of code just above the code where you are getting this error.
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);